# How to include all values of OneToMany mapped field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, groovy

EDIT: Better question overall

I have the following two domains:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="person_id")
    Long id

    @Column(name="person_pidm")
    Long pidm

    @Column(name="person_first_name")
    String first_name

    @Column(name="person_last_name")
    String last_name

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pidm")
    private List<Telephone> phones

    List<Telephone> getPhones() {
        return phones
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="TELEPHONE")
class Telephone implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="telephone_id")
    Long id

    @Column(name="telephone_phone_number")
    String phone_number

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
    private Person pidm;

}
```

With this, I am able to query a person, and get the following response:

```
def result = Person.executeQuery(
    "SELECT s " +
    "FROM Person " +
    "WHERE s.pidm = :pidm",
    [pidm: pidm]
)
```

```json
{
    "id": 186506,
    "first_name": "JANE",
    "last_name": "DOE",
    "pidm": 324950
}
```

But when needed, I would also like to include the `phones` field, and get something like this.

```json
{
    "id": 186506,
    "phones": [
        {
            "id": 329815,
            "phone_number": "1234567890"
        },
        {
            "id": 329816,
            "phone_number": "0987654321"
        }
    ],
    "first_name": "JANE",
    "last_name": "DOE",
    "pidm": 324950
}
```

How would I go about performing the second query to includes the `phones` field?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work out

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="pidm")
@JsonBackReference
private List<SprteleDetail> phones
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
@JsonManagedReference
private Person pidm;
```

@JsonManagedReferences and JsonBackReferences are used to display objects with parent child relationship. @JsonManagedReferences is used to refer to parent object and @JsonBackReferences is used to mark child objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
@JsonIgnore //try this
private Person pidm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add
`@JsonBackReference` on the field you want in the json like

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JsonBackReference
 @JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
 private Person pidm;
```

Comment: This is the answer bro, if you ask same question again they will close the question.

Comment: The answers have been helpful, but they didn't fix my issue. I think I've just been looking at the problem wrong, so I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
@JsonBackReference //try this
private Person pidm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @JsonBackReference to the second table like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TELEPHONE")
class Telephone implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="telephone_id")
    Long id

    @Column(name="telephone_phone_number")
    String phone_number

    @JsonBackReference // add just this line here
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="telephone_pidm", referencedColumnName="person_pidm")
    private Person pidm;

}
```

Comment: The mapping of second table is correct, I just changed the names to make the question more clear. Edited it :)

Comment: Okay i understood your requirement . I have updated my solution accordingly . To get the desired result you just have to add one annotation in your second table Telephone as above. As it will allow spring boot to send Telephone details as Json back in response.